# How to execute code every time a form is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to execute a code every time a form is shown, but the method "Load" and "Shown" only execute the code one time, when I hide this form and show it again it does not execute it.

For the moment I am using another method in the form (created by me) which I call every time before showing the form and after creating a new instance of a class:

```
ProductPage productPage = null;
if (productPage == null)
{
    productPage = NewProductPage;
}

//this is the method that I created to execute the code everytime
productPage.construct();
productPage.Show();
```

But I was wondering if there is any default method like "Load" and "Shown" that executes his code every time the form is shown with form.show();

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by to “hide” a form and to “show it again” because the `Shown` handler gets called every time the form is shown.

Comment: @Symon `Form_Activated` is not perfect either. It will trigger each time he lose the focus and regain it.

Comment: `VisibleChanged` is called when you `Hide()` or `Show()` an existing Form and before the `Shown` event when the Form is first shown. The current status is of course `this.Visible`. The `Shown`  event is raised when the Form is first shown, not when you `Show()` it again after you `Hide()` it. You can also bind the `Visible` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an event called Shown that gets fired after Show is called.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?view=netframework-4.8

There is another that is called when it is Activated
I think this is what you want

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activated?view=netframework-4.8

There is also VisibleChanged on controls.

It is all documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netframework-4.8

This includes focus and validation events for forms at the bottom of the page.